# pymongo insert dict in for loop error

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I was trying to insert a dict to mongodb in a for loop by using pymongo. but I got an error

> InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: 1509261251

However, when I pick a dict output and insert it to mongodb outside the for loop, it works. I don't know why.

here is the code:

```
for i in range(len(re_kw)):
    # read the column
    kw = re_kw.iloc[i]['keywords']

    # Models' prediction   
    re_kw.loc[re_kw['_id'] == re_kw.iloc[i]['_id']].copy()
    re_kw.loc[:, '1'] = sportModel([kw])
    re_kw.loc[:, '5'] = healthyModel([kw])
    re_kw.loc[:, '17'] = sportModel([kw])
    re_kw.loc[:, '38'] = musicModel([kw])

    # Output results to mongoDB
    dic = re_kw.iloc[i].to_dict()
    coll = db['topics'] 
    coll.insert_one(dic)



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidDocument                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-96f38b789987> in <module>()
     13     dic = re_kw.iloc[i].to_dict()
     14     coll = db['topics']
---> 15     coll.insert_one(dic)
     16 
     17 

 ~\Anaconda3\envs\ztdl\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py in 
 insert_one(self, document, bypass_document_validation, session)
     681             self._insert(document,
     682                          bypass_doc_val=bypass_document_validation,
 --> 683                          session=session),
     684             self.write_concern.acknowledged)
     685 

 ~\Anaconda3\envs\ztdl\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py in 
 _insert(self, docs, ordered, check_keys, manipulate, write_concern, op_id, 
 bypass_doc_val, session)
     597             return self._insert_one(
     598                 docs, ordered, check_keys, manipulate, 
     write_concern, op_id,
 --> 599                 bypass_doc_val, session)
     600 
     601         ids = []

 ~\Anaconda3\envs\ztdl\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py in 
 _insert_one(self, doc, ordered, check_keys, manipulate, write_concern, 
 op_id, bypass_doc_val, session)
     577 
     578             result = self.__database.client._retryable_write(
 --> 579                 True, _insert_command, session)
     580             _check_write_command_response(result)
     581         else:

 ~\Anaconda3\envs\ztdl\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py in 
 _retryable_write(self, retryable, func, session)
     1100         """Internal retryable write helper."""
     1101         with self._tmp_session(session) as s:
  -> 1102             return self._retry_with_session(retryable, func, s, 
 None)
     1103 
     1104     def __reset_server(self, address):

~\Anaconda3\envs\ztdl\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py in _retry_with_session(self, retryable, func, session, bulk)
   1077                         # Reset the transaction id and retry the operation.
   1078                         session._retry_transaction_id()
-> 1079                     return func(session, sock_info, retryable)
   1080             except ServerSelectionTimeoutError:
   1081                 if is_retrying():

~\Anaconda3\envs\ztdl\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py in _insert_command(session, sock_info, retryable_write)
    574                     session=session,
    575                     client=self.__database.client,
--> 576                     retryable_write=retryable_write)
    577 
    578             result = self.__database.client._retryable_write(

~\Anaconda3\envs\ztdl\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py in command(self, dbname, spec, slave_ok, read_preference, codec_options, check, allowable_errors, check_keys, read_concern, write_concern, parse_write_concern_error, collation, session, client, retryable_write, publish_events)
    520         # Catch socket.error, KeyboardInterrupt, etc. and close ourselves.
    521         except BaseException as error:
--> 522             self._raise_connection_failure(error)
    523 
    524     def send_message(self, message, max_doc_size):

~\Anaconda3\envs\ztdl\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py in _raise_connection_failure(self, error)
    675             _raise_connection_failure(self.address, error)
    676         else:
--> 677             raise error
    678 
    679     def __eq__(self, other):

~\Anaconda3\envs\ztdl\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py in command(self, dbname, spec, slave_ok, read_preference, codec_options, check, allowable_errors, check_keys, read_concern, write_concern, parse_write_concern_error, collation, session, client, retryable_write, publish_events)
    515                            self.max_bson_size, read_concern,
    516                            parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error,
--> 517                            collation=collation)
    518         except OperationFailure:
    519             raise

~\Anaconda3\envs\ztdl\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py in command(sock, dbname, spec, slave_ok, is_mongos, read_preference, codec_options, session, client, check, allowable_errors, address, check_keys, listeners, max_bson_size, read_concern, parse_write_concern_error, collation)
    100 
    101     request_id, msg, size = message.query(flags, ns, 0, -1, spec,
--> 102                                           None, codec_options, check_keys)
    103 
    104     if (max_bson_size is not None

InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: 1509261251
```

And here is the code that I put it in a try-except block and print the dict.

```
try:
    for i in range(len(df)):
        # 讀取欄位
        kw = df.iloc[i]['keywords']

        # 預測各分群結果   
        df.loc[df['_id'] == df.iloc[i]['_id']].copy()
        df.loc[:, '1'] = sportModel([kw])
        df.loc[:, '5'] = healthyModel([kw])
        df.loc[:, '17'] = sportModel([kw])
        df.loc[:, '38'] = musicModel([kw])

        # 輸出資料至 mongoDB
        dic = df.iloc[i].to_dict()
        coll = db['topics'] 
        coll.insert_one(dic)
except:
    print(dic)
```

I can't put the dict here because stackoverflow said the body can't contain "" so I put it in the comment bellow.

Comment: Can you wrap the point of failure in a try/except block and in the except block print the dictionary causing failure?

Comment: here is the dict which the for loop print:{'38': 0.35454617782747228, '17': 0.022222222222222147, '1': 0.022222222222222147, '_id': '67712c550b63cf58b68d1b5b576c45c2', 'keywords': " '兩岸', '十九大', '中評社', '涉台', '中共', '武統', '變化', '講 話', '和平', '統一', '研討會', '憂慮', '給蔡', '社會', '大陸' ", 'url': 'news.pchome.com.tw/politics/cdnews/20171029/index- 50924602295654250001.html', '5': 0.4152023790580624, 'content': '中評社29日刊登《快評》，全文如下：中共十九大結束之後，各種學習、從我們中評智庫顯地感到，........相信這些變化才剛剛開始，未來還會有更多、更顯明的變化。中央網路 報', 'unix_time': 1509261251}

Comment: The dict looks okay to me. You can also specify your pymongo and mongoDb version to help with debugging

Comment: My pymongo version is 3.6.0 and mongodb v3.4.7